# Grid lines on printed reports

Tags: civireport

Until recently when using the *Print Report* action from a report template, the generated report would include dark gridlines separating the rows and columns, but now the gridlines no longer appear. Is there a way to toggle the gridlines on and off or update the default to include the lines again?

Comment: Maybe you have changed themes on your site? Does the problem also happen on the public demo for the report you're looking at? https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org I see gridlines there.